# Webconfig for a Typescript and jquery app

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, express, webpack

I had an app, full JS, based on NodeJS Express and a simple jQuery-based UI (using EJS templates). I recently migrated the entire code to Typescript. The backend is working fine, but I need some help with the UI code.

I have issues getting my UI working with TS.

In more details, my UI works as follows:

- Each page is rendered by my express backend from an EJS template. Also, there's a JS (now TS) script embedded in each page from which I get the data, also from the backend (via a REST API).
- When doing the migration, I shared some type definitions between my backend and frontend code (e.g. DTOs, models, etc.)

My folder structure:

```
/
|-- dist/  (emitted TS files)
|-- src/
|---- views/   (ejs templates)
|---- controllers/   (frontend serving endpoints)
|-------- api/   (api endpoints)
|-- lib/   (shared TS code between backend and frontend)
|-- public/   (frontend TS code)
```

My tsconfig.ts lives in /src

I'm not sure how to make this setup working. I guess I need to use webpack or a tsconfig. The first problem I had was that my tsconfig modules is setup as "CommonJS", which (of course) doesn't work directly on a browser. I actually tried creating a separate tsconfig.ts for my UI app (include: [src/public/**/*]), but because I'm using some files in lib, TS is adding to its compilation files outside /public. Btw, my app does compile from a TS perspective.

Any help how can I get this seemingly simple setup?

(included this info in my question)